# Is the following sentence true or false according to Mathematical logic?

Tags: logic

The following question probably philosophical and as a result maybe not fit here, but I consider it as a Mathematical logic question:

"If there are no roads, then all roads lead to Rome."

Is this sentence true or false?

Comment: Cf. [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)

Comment: Thanks. That was short, but still appropriate. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of questions and answers about vacuous truth. Let us try a variation and touch on some heuristic points.

There is a parallelism between *logically* drawing any consequence from an inconsistent set of formulas and *logically* saying anything about a non-existent "thing" (already a *contradictio in adjecto* if left unqualified). In both cases, there is nothing to put a logical limit to what can be drawn or said. Thus, when they occur in an antecedent position, anything follows.

If we suspect whether there is a gap in our assessment, the reliable way is to translate the statement into a sentence in formal language and thereafter analyse it. The statement in the question can be translated as

$$\neg\exists x(Road(x))\rightarrow\forall x(Road(x)\rightarrow Rome(x))$$

An excellent online tool to check validity is Wolfgang Schwarz's [Tree Proof Generator](https://www.umsu.de/trees/). When we feed the sentence into the tool, we obtain

[image]

as expected.